# Fatal Error: Index out of range tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

Can anybody see where i am going wrong? The tableView controller should display either 1 or 4 sections (depending on input from the previous View Controller) along with a dynamic number of rows coming from the **array(s)**.

The program is supposed to populate each section with a different array however i am receiving an Index out of range error in the third case in the Switch statement. The sections and rows are set in the `viewdidLoad()` method and the `selectPic()` method changes `houseImg` variable accordingly.

I'm using **Swift 4**.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        if checkData == 0 {
            //Inserting one section and filling the cells with the array
            saveCount = pupilNames.count
                if saveCount > counter{
                    cell.imageView?.image = houseImg
                    cell.textLabel?.text = "Pupil Name:  \(pupilNames[indexPath.row])"
                    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Score:  \(pupilScores[indexPath.row])"
                    counter = counter+1
                }
            checkData = 2
            return cell
        }
        else if checkData == 1 {
            //Inserting four sections and populate 4 arrays for each section
            var countIf: Int = 0
            var secondCount: Int = 0
            houseCount = 4
                if checkCount > houseCont {
                    switch houseCont {
                        case 0:
                            chosenHouse = 1
                            selectPic()
                            countIf = pupilNames.count
                            repeat {
                                cell.imageView?.image = houseImg
                                cell.textLabel?.text = "Pupil Name:  \(pupilNames[indexPath.row])"
                                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Score:   \(pupilScores[indexPath.row])"
                                secondCount = secondCount+1
                            } while countIf > secondCount
                        case 1:
                            chosenHouse = 2
                            selectPic()
                            countIf = secondNames.count
                            secondCount = 0
                            repeat {
                                cell.imageView?.image = houseImg
                                cell.textLabel?.text = "Pupil Name:  \(secondNames[indexPath.row])"
                                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Score:   \(secondScores[indexPath.row])"
                                secondCount = secondCount+1
                            } while countIf > secondCount
                        case 2:
                            chosenHouse = 3
                            selectPic()
                            countIf = thirdNames.count
                            secondCount = 0
                            repeat {
                                cell.imageView?.image = houseImg
                                //*******Error occurring on Pupil Name line *********
                                cell.textLabel?.text = "Pupil Name:  \(thirdNames[indexPath.row])"
                                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Score:   \(thirdScores[indexPath.row])"
                                secondCount = secondCount+1
                            } while countIf > secondCount
                        case 3:
                            chosenHouse = 4
                            selectPic()
                            repeat {
                                cell.imageView?.image = houseImg
                                cell.textLabel?.text = "Pupil Name:  \(fourNames[indexPath.row])"
                                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Score:   \(fourScores[indexPath.row])"
                                secondCount = secondCount+1
                            }while countIf > secondCount
                    default:
                            houseCont = 5
                            checkData = 2
                    }
                    houseCont = houseCont+1
                }
        }
    return cell
}
```

**Edit:**
'houseCount' is sent from the previous view controller and contains a value of one or four. 'saveCount' contains a number created by adding up the count of all arrays, this is done in the method that populates the arrays.

`saveCount = pupilNames.count+secondNames.count+thirdNames.count+fourNames.count`

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
    return houseCount
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return saveCount
}
```

**Final Edit:** Thanks for all the help everyone, it was a mixture of both answers that helped me to resolve my error. This is my final code that fixed my problem, i removed the if statement and the repeat loop as well as changed some bits of code in order to fix my problem.

```
else if checkData == 1 {
            houseCount = 4
                    switch indexPath.section {
                        case 0:
                            chosenHouse = 1
                            selectPic()
                                cell.imageView?.image = houseImg
                                cell.textLabel?.text = "Pupil Name:  \(pupilNames[indexPath.row])"
                                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Score:   \(pupilScores[indexPath.row])"
                        case 1:
                            chosenHouse = 2
                            selectPic()
                                cell.imageView?.image = houseImg
                                cell.textLabel?.text = "Pupil Name:  \(secondNames[indexPath.row])"
                                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Score:   \(secondScores[indexPath.row])"
                        case 2:
                            chosenHouse = 3
                            selectPic()
                                cell.imageView?.image = houseImg
                                cell.textLabel?.text = "Pupil Name:  \(thirdNames[indexPath.row])"
                                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Score:   \(thirdScores[indexPath.row])"
                        case 3:
                            chosenHouse = 4
                            selectPic()
                            //saveCount = fourNames.count
                                cell.imageView?.image = houseImg
                                cell.textLabel?.text = "Pupil Name:  \(fourNames[indexPath.row])"
                                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Score:   \(fourScores[indexPath.row])"
                    default:
                            houseCont = 5
                            checkData = 2
                    }
                    houseCont = houseCont+1
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us your `numberOfRows` & `numberOfSection` method implementation?

Comment: those `repeat` loops look really wrong and suspicious.. why do you rewrite texts n times instead of simply setting the last value, the one that you want to have there? moreover, you are talking about sections, but right now it seems that you are completely ignoring `indexPath.section`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the following code, a couple of alarm bells are going off:

```
                       chosenHouse = 3
                       selectPic()
                       countIf = thirdNames.count
                       secondCount = 0
                       repeat {
                            cell.imageView?.image = houseImg
                            //*******Error occurring on Pupil Name line *********
                            cell.textLabel?.text = "Pupil Name:  \(thirdNames[indexPath.row])"
                            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Score:   \(thirdScores[indexPath.row])"
                            secondCount = secondCount+1
                        } while countIf > secondCount
```

Firstly the use of `repeat`. The code inside always gets executed at least once. I think this would be an error in the case that `thirdNames.count == 0`

However, even more oddly, the content of the repeat loop does not change between iterations. You don't do anything that depends on the only thing that changes - `secondCount`.  If `countIf` were 10, you'd simply assign the same name and score  to the same two controls 10 times.

Comment: `thirdNames.count` can never be equal to 0 or the button to display the Table View Controller will not be enabled. Does that mean i need to increment the array or the Index Path?

Comment: "Does that mean i need to increment the array or the Index Path?" I would expect you to be using a different cell and different data on each iteration, otherwise what is the point?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but according to me in the last switch statement,when it is executing there is problem while inserting to the sections because it might be exceeding index path row count somehow. Also the way code is written not taking into account the indexPath.section .

Comment: I am new to swift and still learning the syntax, could i implement this into my switch statement?

Comment: You can try using " override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {} for defining the number of rows for a particular section . And then you can use func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {} in which u can switch sections using switch indexPath.section  and do the corresponding coding for each section.